# plotting heatmaps with kepler.gl

Tags: python, geospatial, kepler.gl

I have a pandas DataFrame with the following schema:

```
zip_name: string
zip_code_geom: string
score: double
```

I am attempting to plot a heatmap with `score` as the scale. How do I modify the following code to produce a heatmap visualization in kepler.gl?

```
df['score'] = df['score'].astype('float32')

# Convert geometries to WKT format
df['geometry_wkt'] = df['zip_code_geom'].apply(lambda geom: geom.wkt)

map1 = KeplerGl(
                 height=600, 
                 config={
                         'mapState': {'latitude': 39.8097343, 'longitude': -98.5556199, 'zoom': 3}, 
                         'title': 'scores'
                        }, 
                show_docs=False
                )
                
map1.add_data(
              data=df, 
              name="scores"
             )

# Show the map
display_kepler(map1)
```

The above code creates a base layer map visualization with geometries, but doesn't plot a heatmap.